# Running "create-rmi-keystore.bat" file in Jmeter bin folder not working

Tags: jmeter

I'm trying to set up distributed test in Jmeter however whenever I tried to run the "create-rmi-keystore.bat" file in bin folder doesn't seem to work.. It's not opening...Can someone enlighten me what should be the problem and solution.

Answer (score 4):

Nobody can "enlighten" you about the solution unless you run this command in the terminal and share the output with us, the possible reasons are:

1. You already have `rmi_keystore.jks` file in the "bin" folder of your JMeter installation
2. You don't have [`keytool`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/keytool.html) program in your operating system [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable))

I also believe that 99.99999% of users don't need secure communication between JMeter master and slaves as it doesn't add any value and just consuming valuable resources, so I tend to disable secure RMI communication when I run JMeter tests in distributed mode.

1. Add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

   ```
   server.rmi.ssl.disable=true
   ```
2. Restart JMeter to pick the property up
3. Repeat it for all machines which are involved in distributed test
4. That's it, you don't need this rmi-keystore.jks anymore

References:

- [Remote hosts and RMI configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html)
- [JMeter Distributed Testing with Docker](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-distributed-testing-with-docker/)
- [Remote Testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html)

Comment: are there any impact if we dont include the rmi-keystore.jks to our jmeter test?

Comment: hi sir, do we need to change also the server.rmi.ssl.disable line to "true" in jmeter.properties file?

Answer (score 1):

SO Windows

for the create-rmi-keystore file to open correctly, you need to configure your account's environment variables, both JAVA_HOME (with the JAVA folder path):

- Example: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_202

And also add the JAVA /bin path to the PATH:

- Example: C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_202\bin

Answer (score 0):

On Unix system use [create-rmi-keystore.sh](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#setup_ssl) script instead

> for Windows systems (called bin/create-rmi-keystore.bat) and Unix like systems (called bin/create-rmi-keystore.sh)
>
> ```
> $ ./create-rmi-keystore.sh
> ```

Comment: im using windows bin/create-rmi-keystore.bat is not running when I clicked.